# Exception in Mongo write when removing multiple documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to remove documents which meet certain criteria...

**server/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  rA: function (a) {
        As.remove({aId:a}, {multi:true});
    }
});
```

`As` collection has documents with the same `aId`, it is `a`

**client/js**

```
var a = this.aId;
Meteor.call('rA', a);
```

I got following error on my terminal:

```
I20151231-06:39:24.849(7)? Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a function
I20151231-06:39:24.850(7)?     at packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:322:1
I20151231-06:39:24.851(7)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
```

How do I remove multiple documents?

Thank you and happy new year... ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `{multi:true}` for the removing method. It should be

`As.remove({aId:a});`

`multi` is only for update. Check out the documentation in [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update)

Comment: helloo @ThaiTran thanks for your answer.. i thought that alone will only remove 1 document,,i'll try then,,,